# get perticular progressbar based on id and update its value with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have multiple progressbars i want to get perticular progressbar based on id and update its value in angularjs

please give the solution

```
<progressbar value="0" id="seekbar1"></progressbar>
<progressbar value="0" id="seekbar2"></progressbar>
<progressbar value="0" id="seekbar3"></progressbar>
```

in controller i wrote like this but it is not working

```
var progress = document.getElementById("seekbar1");
progress.value=30;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using angular as it should be used. The whole idea of angular is that the single point of truth is the model. The view is generated from the model. You update the model, and the view changes accordingly.

You should have a controller with

```
$scope.progress1 = 0;
$scope.progress2 = 0;
$scope.progress3 = 0;
```

And the view should be

```
<progressbar value="progress1"></progressbar>
<progressbar value="progress2"></progressbar>
<progressbar value="progress3"></progressbar>
```

If you want to set the first progress bar to 30, you just need to do

```
$scope.progress1 = 30;
```